# Errors when re-compiling a .dll

Tags: c#, dll, serial-port, visual-studio-2015, recompile

I'm getting the following errors when I try to rebuild a .dll

Please advise what can I replace these lines with so that the code will compile.

Background info (likely not relevant):

The .dll is part of an add-in output module for a program that controls Christmas lights. It outputs data from the program to the selected serial port telling the connected relay board which relays are to be on or off.
I intend to modify the output to suit my device so instead of the output being FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 for relay 1 2 3 on and 4 5 6 7 8 off it will send the appropriate format for the board That I have. (see below)

http://www.tinyosshop.com/image/data/board_modules/usbrelay4-5.jpg

Error   CS0571  'SerialSetupDialog.SelectedPort.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

It references the line in this section:

```
private void buttonSerialSetup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SerialSetupDialog serialSetupDialog = new SerialSetupDialog(this.m_selectedPort);
  if (((Form) serialSetupDialog).ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    return;
  this.m_selectedPort = serialSetupDialog.get_SelectedPort();
}
```

Also there are 3 cases of:
Error   CS0221  Constant value '-128' cannot be converted to a 'byte' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)

The compiler doesn't like this part of the code. "(byte) sbyte.MinValue;"

```
private void Protocol1Event(byte[] channelValues)
{
  int length1 = channelValues.Length;
  int count = 2;
  int length2 = 2 + 2 * length1 + (2 + 2 * length1) / 100;
  if (this.m_p1Packet.Length < length2)
    this.m_p1Packet = new byte[length2];
  this.m_p1Packet[0] = (byte) 126;
  this.m_p1Packet[1] = (byte) sbyte.MinValue;
  this.m_threadPosition = 10;
  for (int index = 0; index < length1; ++index)
  {
    if ((int) channelValues[index] == 125)
    {
      this.m_threadPosition = 11;
      this.m_p1Packet[count++] = (byte) 124;
    }
    else if ((int) channelValues[index] == 126)
    {
      this.m_threadPosition = 12;
      this.m_p1Packet[count++] = (byte) 124;
    }
    else if ((int) channelValues[index] == (int) sbyte.MaxValue)
    {
      this.m_threadPosition = 13;
      this.m_p1Packet[count++] = (byte) sbyte.MinValue;
    }
    else
    {
      this.m_threadPosition = 14;
      this.m_p1Packet[count++] = channelValues[index];
    }
    if (count % 100 == 0)
    {
      this.m_threadPosition = 15;
      this.m_p1Packet[count++] = (byte) 125;
    }
    this.m_threadPosition = 16;
  }
  this.m_threadPosition = 17;
  if (this.m_running)
  {
    while (this.m_selectedPort.WriteBufferSize - this.m_selectedPort.BytesToWrite <= count)
      Thread.Sleep(10);
    this.m_threadPosition = 18;
    this.m_selectedPort.Write(this.m_p1Packet, 0, count);
    this.m_threadPosition = 19;
  }
  this.m_threadPosition = 20;
}

private void Protocol2Event(byte[] channelValues)
{
  byte num1 = (byte) sbyte.MinValue;
  int length = channelValues.Length;
  byte[] array = new byte[8];
  int num2 = 0;
  while (num2 < length)
  {
    int num3 = Math.Min(num2 + 7, length - 1);
    this.m_p2Packet[1] = num1++;
    if (num3 >= length - 1)
      this.m_p2Zeroes.CopyTo((Array) this.m_p2Packet, 3);
    Array.Clear((Array) array, 0, 8);
    for (int index = num2; index <= num3; ++index)
    {
      byte num4 = channelValues[index];
      byte num5 = num4;
      if ((int) num4 >= 1 && (int) num4 <= 8)
        array[(int) num4 - 1] = (byte) 1;
      else if ((int) num5 >= 1 && (int) num5 <= 8)
        array[(int) num5 - 1] = (byte) 1;
    }
    byte num6 = (byte) (1 + Array.IndexOf<byte>(array, (byte) 0));
    this.m_p2Packet[2] = num6;
    int index1 = num2;
    int count = 3;
    while (index1 <= num3)
    {
      this.m_p2Packet[count] = (byte) ((uint) channelValues[index1] - (uint) num6);
      ++index1;
      ++count;
    }
    if (this.m_running)
      this.m_selectedPort.Write(this.m_p2Packet, 0, count);
    num2 += 8;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `(byte)sbyte.MinValue;` throws an error is because [sbytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d86he86x.aspx) minimal value is -128 whereas [bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) minimal value is 0. Therefore converting that to the other will cause an overflow. If you really want this behaviour you can use the keyword [unchecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) as the following:

```
byte b = unchecked((byte)sbyte.MinValue);
```

However this will give `b` the value of 128.

To answer the other part of your question I believe that replacing:

```
serialSetupDialog.get_SelectedPort();
```

with:

```
serialSetupDialog.SelectedPort;
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks :) that did the trick (error gone) Just that 1 other error left now.
I'm not sure if its intended but will assume it was as it was working in the original.

Comment: Through trial and error I manage to sort out the other error.

I replaced:
serialSetupDialog.get_SelectedPort(); 
with:
serialSetupDialog.SelectedPort;

Comment: Nice simple fix, thanks for the update, added into my answer so it is complete